# Как построить динамическое условие в PHP?

Tags: php

Пытаюсь сделать калькулятор.
Есть массив правил, в котором описано какая переменная должна быть <,>,=,!= итд какому то значению, например:

```
["sum",">","20"]
```

выражение составляет пользователь и что он туда пропишет неизвестно заранее.
То есть может пояявится например:

```
["sum",">","20"]
["sum","!=","30"]
["sum","=>","777"]
```

а мне в свою очередь нужно взять этот массив и составить правило, по которому я должен искать значения, например:

```
if ($sum > 20){правило сработало, чтото делаем}
if ($sum != 30){правило сработало, чтото делаем}
if ($sum => 777){правило сработало, чтото делаем}
```

это вообще реально решить? У меня опыта не хватает :-)

Comment: вместо "sum" в массиве должно быть число, вместо знаков тоже число и ваш if заработает

Comment: не понял, можно пример? как вместо знаков число?

Comment: Читайте http://php.net/manual/ru/function.version-compare.php

Comment: Напишите оригинальную задачу, из которой появилась эта. Сейчас вы пытаетесь повторить виртуальную машину, в которой у вас все выполняется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если делать в ООП стиле, то Вам необходимо описать новый тип данных, который будет представлять Ваши правила, как Вы их называете.

Например:

```
<?php 
interface RuleInterface {

     /**
     *@return bool
     */
     public function resolve();

}
```

И конкретные реализации этих правил, например:

```
Equal.php

<?php
class Equal implements RuleInterface {

   private $a;

   private $b;

   public function __construct($a, $b)
   {
     $this->a = $a;
     $this->b = $b;
   }

   public function resolve($a, $b)
   {
     return $a === $b;
   }

}

GreaterThan.php

<?php
class GreaterThan implements RuleInterface {

   private $a;

   private $b;

   public function __construct($a, $b)
   {
     $this->a = $a;
     $this->b = $b;
   }

    public function resolve()
    {
      return $a > $b;
    }

}
```

Потом Вам надо сделать фабрику, в которую Вы передавали бы результат ввода пользователя, а она бы Вам создавала на его основе правильный экземпляр типа RuleInterface, у которого Вы вызывали бы метод `resolve()` и получали бы нужный результат.

Фабрика:

```
<?php
interface RulesFactory {

  /**
  *@param array $input
  *@return RuleInterface 
  */
  public function createRule(array $input);

}


<?php
class SimpleRulesFactory implements RulesFactory {

  public function createRule($array $input)
  {
    swith($input[1]) {
      case '=' :
        return new Equal($input[0], $input[2]);
      case '>' :
        return new GreaterThan($input[0], $input[2]);
      default :
        throw new Exception(); 
    }
  }

}
```

Пример:

```
<?php
$sum = 25;
$input = [
  [$sum, '>', 20],
  [$sum, '=', 25]
];
$factory = new SimpleRulesFactory();
foreach ($input as $row) {
  $rule = $factory->create($row);
  if ($rule->resolve()) {
    // правило сработало, что-то делаем
  }
}
```